# Eclipse Mars: code is gone

Tags: java, eclipse

Please, help! I opened Eclipse Mars to continue coding and my code is gone! I don't know what could have caused this but it's all gone. Does anyone have any idea what can I do?

[image]

Note: I tried to right-click the java file->Replace With->Previous from local history. But a message says "No local history available for selected resource". Is there any other way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you move some files around or do some cleaning up? Could you have inadvertently deleted the files outside of Eclipse?

Comment: No, it's not possible. I never go to the workspace folder.

Comment: I just use Eclipse. But I've been having to import the workspace everytime I launch Eclipse, I dont know why..

Comment: That's not normal, so something is seriously wrong with your installation.  However, without access to your computer it is going to be really hard for anyone here to help you.  Do you have any colleagues that can help?  StackOverflow is probably not the right place to be asking for help on this.

Comment: I will try reinstalling Eclipse. I just found a solution. I had to go to .metadata/.history and search for some backup and I found it. It seems Eclipse saves the src files automatically.

Comment: Thank you anyway Jim! And I will ask my colleagues if they can help me on this. Eclipse is really pissing me off.

Answer (score 1):

The first step in debugging this problem is to find out if the code is still exists without using Eclipse. Several possibilities come to mind:

1. The code is still where you expect, the files exist and the content is OK.
2. The code is still where you expect, the files exist, but the files are empty.
3. The workspace directory does not exist any more.

You need to use a file explorer program to find the files and check they are not empty. Try opening them with Notepad++ or similar. If you are lucky, option 1 will be the answer, and Eclipse has got confused. Just use File/Switch Workspace to set the workspace to the directory and all should come right.

Options 2 & 3 indicate you have lost data. There is probably little chance of recovery. Revert to your backups (you do have them?). Otherwise learn a lesson and set up a GIT or SVN server (or subscribe to a cloud service). I just use a very old laptop running Ubuntu with SVN server installed.

As a side issue, Eclipse does not randomly delete or empty files. There are millions of developers world-wide using Eclipse, and if it existed,  such behavior would be all over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found my file with a strange name in local history with this path:

".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/"

It was not the last version but better than nothing :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).